# CSS div doesn't show up

Tags: css, html

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id= "body">
        Hello
        <div id= "notr">
            <div id="slika">
            </div>
            <div id="besedilo">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color: brown;
    font-family: "comic sans ms";
    border: 1 solid black;
    font-size: 200%;
}

notr {
    border: 1 solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Div name "notr" is the problem that i can´t see it.Page should look like this:

http://shrani.najdi.si/?3L/x5/3gUJm56s/sa.jpg

"Notr" is the div that should be the Div that is light-brown color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With CSS, you need to label IDs like this:

```
#notr {
    border:1px solid black;
    height:20px;
    width:30px;
}
```

Without the `#` it is looking for a tag, like `<notr>`, which is obviously not what you want. Heads up, I also took the liberty of correcting your `border` syntax ... you need to include a measurement unit (`px`, `em`, or `rem`), so it would be `1px solid black`.

**Edit**

The reason it has the "same background-color" as `body` (the parent of that `div`), is because by default `div`s have `background-color:transparent;`. If you wanted to give it a different color, try something like this:

```
#notr {
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:20px;
    width:30px;
}
```

And voila ... magically it is a different color. ;) [Even have a jsFiddle to prove it!](http://jsfiddle.net/t3FQe/)

**Another edit**

Looking at your answer, *"Notr" is the div that should be the Div that is light-brown color*. Well then it shouldn't be on the body bro!

```
body {
    font-family: "comic sans ms";
    font-size: 200%;
}

#notr {
    background-brown;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:20px;
    width:30px;
}
```

[Here is a second jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3FQe/2/), which I think gives what you want.

Comment: Still not working only brown background from body div

Comment: @user3013951 Did you include the `1px solid black;` for the border as well?

Comment: @user3013951 - your syntax of `1 solid black` would not work, you need to specify **px**, hence the `1px solid black` in my answer. and you did not specify a different color for `#notr` in your CSS, so I'm not sure if your expecting it to magically be purple or something haha. the default value of a `div`'s `background-color` is `transparent`.

Comment: @user3013951 - i expanded my comment and answer to explain why your `#notr` div would have the same `background-color` as the parent. if you want to give it a different color ... give it a different color.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of minor issues.

1) You must use a `#` sign before an ID selector in CSS before `notr`

2) Not sure if this is just my coding practices but i always indicate a unit of measurement in css - e.g where you have set your border using "1 solid black" i would use "1px solid black"

```
#notr {
    border:1px solid black;
    height:20px;
    width:30px;
}
```

Demo jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4F5WA/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="body">Hello
    <div id="notr">
        <div id="slika"></div>
        <div id="besedilo"></div>
    </div>
</div>

body {
    background-color:brown;
    font-family:"comic sans ms";
    border: 1 solid black;
    font-size:200%;
}
#notr {
    border:1px solid black;
    height:20px;

    width:30px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7jG9/2/)

Two mistakes of yours notr which should be `#notr` and `border:1px solid black;` in the css file check the fiddle